# Saving multiple PFFiles in parallel in Swift3

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift3, bolts-framework

After upgrading a Swift 2 project to Swift 3, I struggle with the `BFTask`/`PFFile` APIs of Parse.

I want to save a number of Parse files in parallel. So far I used `BFTask.forCompletionOfAllTasks` which got passed an array of `BFTask`s which were generated by `PFFile.saveInBackground`. Before migrating to Swift 3, this worked great:

```
let files: [PFFile] = ...
let tasks: [BFTask] = files.map { $0.saveInBackground() }
BFTask(forCompletionOfAllTasks: tasks)
  .continueWithSuccessBlock { ... }
```

However, with Swift 3 this does not work anymore: `BFTask.forCompletionOfAllTasks` now returns a `BFTask<NSNumber>` which is not accepted by `forCompletionOfAllTasks` which demands an array of `<BFTask<AnyObject>`.

Any help on this is appreciated. How can I convert `BFTask<NSNumber>` to `<BFTask<AnyObject>` -- or is there another way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by force-casting the image-saving tasks to `BFTask<AnyObject>`:

`let tasks = files.map { $0.saveInBackground() as! BFTask<AnyObject> }`

Now `tasks` can be passed to `BFTask<AnyObject>.forCompletionOfAllTasksWithResults`.